# colors in ggplot barplot with two stacked bars mixed

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I try to plot a ggplot stacked barplot with two different graded colors for each of the two bars. Each value in the df gets assigned a color code in hex. However the colors are mixed between the two bars.

I tried multiple approaches to get this fixe but it seems I do not fully understand the logic behind this yet.
I can imagine there is a simple and elegant solution to this.

This would be the case:

```
# raw data
values <- c(156182263, 51298256, 673688260, 232926061, 0, 104869535, 398192679, 0, 0, 10782158, 27256840, 70810639, 97336000, 169901000, 0, 51202000, 1261181000, 112863000, 85185000, 61680000, 0, 0, 0)
id <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

# construct the df
df <- data.frame(values, id)

# sort the df by id and values
df <- df[with(df, order(id, -values)), ]

# construct object to use for plotting
dat.m <- melt(df, id.vars = "id")

# generate the color for each value
col_f_a <- colorRampPalette(c("aquamarine2", "white"))
col_a <- col_f_a(length(df$id[df$id == 0]))
col_f_b <- colorRampPalette(c("steelblue1", "white"))
col_b <- col_f_b(length(df$id[df$id == 1]))

# get the colors to their respective value in the object for plotting
cols <- vector()
cols <- append(cols, col_a)
cols <- append(cols, col_b)
dat.m["col"] <- cols

# plot
ggplot(dat.m, aes(x = id, y = value, fill = cols)) +
  geom_bar(color = "black", stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = cols) +
  geom_hline(yintercept = 1000000000, lwd = 2) +
  theme(axis.line=element_blank(),
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.text.y=element_blank(),
        axis.ticks=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        legend.position="none",
        panel.background=element_blank(),
        panel.border=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
        plot.background=element_blank())
```

Comment: You want `scale_fill_identity`, since you precalculated which values to use. `scale_fill_manual` remaps a discrete variable to a color palette without precalculating.

Comment: so far so good, the coloring problem is solved with `scale_fill_identity`. Thank you! However the color gets more pronounced the higher the layer, which I wish to have reversed. I tried reversing the data and the color both inside ggplot and outside but nothing got it fixed, any ideas?